# How to change dynamic created textbox Content after using FindName?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, wpf-controls, buttonclick

I have created a dynamic `TextBox` in a `WrapPanel` which I want to change on a button click event.

I am finding the control using `FindName`, but what should I do after this? Alternatively, is there different way to find the control using `Name`?

Here is my code:

```
WrapPanel wpOrderList = new WrapPanel();
TextBox txtCount = new TextBox();
txtCount.Text = "1";
txtCount.Height = 20;
txtCount.Width = 20;
txtCount.Name = "txtCount_" + global;
wpOrderList.Children.Add(txtCount);

void btnPlus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string[] strngname = (sender as Button).Name.ToString().Split('_');
        this.FindName("txtCount_" + strngname[1]);
        //What should I do to change the textbox text now here?
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xaml

```
         <StackPanel x:Name="stk">
            <Button Click="Button_Click_1"  Height="50">Click</Button>
        </StackPanel>
```

In Windows Loaded Event

```
            WrapPanel wpOrderList = new WrapPanel();
            TextBox txtCount = new TextBox();
            txtCount.Text = "1";
            txtCount.Height = 20;
            txtCount.Width = 20;
            txtCount.Name = "txt";
            wpOrderList.Children.Add(txtCount);
            stk.Children.Add(wpOrderList);
```

On Button Click

```
           TextBox foundTextBox = FindChild<TextBox>(this, "txt");

            foundTextBox.Text = "fdf";
```

Helper Function

```
public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
           where T : DependencyObject
        {
            // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
            if (parent == null) return null;

            T foundChild = null;

            int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                // If the child is not of the request child type child
                T childType = child as T;
                if (childType == null)
                {
                    // recursively drill down the tree
                    foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                    // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
                    if (foundChild != null) break;
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
                {
                    var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                    // If the child's name is set for search
                    if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                    {
                        // if the child's name is of the request name
                        foundChild = (T)child;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // child element found.
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return foundChild;
        }
```

Complete Code in code behind

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox foundTextBox = FindChild<TextBox>(this, "txt");

            foundTextBox.Text = "fdf";
        }

        public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
           where T : DependencyObject
        {
            // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
            if (parent == null) return null;

            T foundChild = null;

            int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                // If the child is not of the request child type child
                T childType = child as T;
                if (childType == null)
                {
                    // recursively drill down the tree
                    foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                    // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
                    if (foundChild != null) break;
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
                {
                    var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                    // If the child's name is set for search
                    if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                    {
                        // if the child's name is of the request name
                        foundChild = (T)child;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // child element found.
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return foundChild;
        }


        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WrapPanel wpOrderList = new WrapPanel();
            TextBox txtCount = new TextBox();
            txtCount.Text = "1";
            txtCount.Height = 20;
            txtCount.Width = 20;
            txtCount.Name = "txt";
            wpOrderList.Children.Add(txtCount);
            stk.Children.Add(wpOrderList);
        }    
    }
```

Comment: I am getting null in return.

Comment: I think your textbox creation code is not executing

Comment: My textbox is created successfully as I have checked in Visualizer.

Comment: you have added the textbox inside a wrap panel.But the wrap panel is not added to the window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98911/discussion-between-0mv1-and-justin-ci).

Comment: How to use this function?

Comment: just copy paste the "FindChild" Helper function in your class

Comment: I know just copy and paste but I am asking how to call that function and what I have to pass in arguments?

Comment: You have to pass "this" and the textbox name,when your are calling from button click

Comment: FindChild<TextBox>(this, "txtBoxname");

Comment: Ok Justin let me try it.

Comment: It's working Justin Thank you so much exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: A Happy Merry Christmas to you too. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var textbox = this.FindName("txtCount_" + strngname[1]) as TextBox;

if (textbox != null)
   textbox.Text = "Test";
```

Comment: No result return null

Comment: What is the button's name?

Comment: btnPlus, I think it doesn't matter what the button name is? I am calling the function and it is there btnPlus_Click.

Comment: You are calling Split method on button's name. Its name is 'btnPlus'. So instead of array with 2 entries (like 'btn' and number) you get wrong data. Using it leads to NRE.

Comment: I am splitting the button name because the number after btnPlus_ is 1 like btnPlus_1 same as txtCount_1 to find the textbox control sorry I forgot to tell you button full name but still I am not getting it!